# django - collecting data from a HTML <select>

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've seen a couple of documents on how to collect the data from a  HTML statement in Django but none of them were very clear to me. Does anybody have a real working example to share?

In my case I have something like this in my template file:

```
<select title="my_options">
   <option value="1">Select value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Select value 2</option>
</select>
```

What goes in the views.py in order to collect the selected value? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a GET request, `request.GET['my_options']`. If it's a POST, then `request.POST['my_options']`. This will be a string, either `"1"` or `"2"` (or `"<script>alert('I hacked you!')</script>"`)

Either way, it's probably better to use the [Django forms framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) to save you the hassle of writing the HTML, and sanitizing the returned values.

Comment: I second using Django Forms, even if you want to write the HTML yourself (which the docs will help you do).

Comment: In that case what would be a good example for the <select> using the django forms? My page has only one form with a select (like the one in the question) and a submit button.

Comment: If I do request.POST['my_options'] i get this error: list index out of range.

Comment: Create a `Form` class with a `ChoiceField`, say `my_options`. Stuff it into your template context. Then your entire `<select>` tag boils down to `{{ form.my_options }}`. Process the form as in the example from the documentation.

Comment: `request.POST` should be a dict-like object. I don't think it could ever throw an `IndexError` unless you're doing something very strange.

Comment: As per your suggestion I decided to use django forms instead of building that <select> by hand. Now I just have to figure out how I can load data to that select statement from the database. The options in my select statement change based on a database lookup.

Comment: That's easy enough if you use [`ModelChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Manage data via POST

```
def yourView(request):
    # Use '.get('id', None)' in case you don't receive it, avoid getting error
    selected_option = request.POST.get('my_options', None)  

    if selected_option:
        # Do what you need with the variable
```

One thing that may be useful with forms in Django is to make different things if you make a POST  to the URL or just load it:

```
def yourView(request):

    if request.POST:  # If this is true, the view received POST
        selected_option = request.POST.get('my_options', None)
        if selected_option:
            # Do what you need to do with the variables
        return render_to_response(...)

return render_to_response(...)
```

There are 2 `render_to_response` in case you need to do different things if the view was just loaded or receive a POST.

## Manage data via GET

```
def yourView(request):
    # Use '.get('id', None)' in case you don't receive it, avoid getting error
    selected_option = request.GET.get('my_options', None)  

    if selected_option:
        # Do what you need with the variable
```

Comment: shouldn't it be name rather than id?