# How to get data from selection menu to backend/sever

Tags: python, html, django, forms, view

I've created a drop down menu which contains 5 choices. When a user selects a choice and presses the submit button, how do I transfer that "selection" to the backend/server in Django?

After that, when the value of the selection reaches the backend, I intend to use the value to create another form. There are 5 forms to choose from (one for each choice) and the type of form that appears will depend on the value of the original selection.

This is what I have so far, but I get the error, "Key 'selection' not found in QueryDict: {}"

Here's the HTML file:

```
<div id = "f1" style="display:none">
  <form name= "form1" action='/products/{{ action }}/' method='get'>
    <p class="choice-header"> Product: </p>
    <select id = "g1" title="selection" onchange = "showForm()">
      <option value = "0">--</option>
      <option value = "1">Form 1</option>
      <option value = "2">Form 2</option>
      <option value = "3">Form 3</option>
      <option value = "4">Form 4</option>
      <option value = "5">Form 5</option>
    </select>
    <div id= "b1" style="display:none">
      <input class="button" type=submit value="{{ button }}">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's the Django views.py file

```
def new2(request):
  form_no = request.GET["selection"]

  if form_no == 1:
    form_to = Form1()
  c = RequestContext(request, {
    'action': 'add/2',
    'button': 'Add', 
    'form': form_to,
  })
  return render_to_response('links/add.html', c)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Django issue. You just haven't given your `select` element a `name` attribute.

```
<select id="g1" name="selection">
```

Comment: Wow, that did it! But now I get a new error: local variable 'form_to' referenced before assignment. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help, I'm new at this!

Comment: Because `form_no` isn't `1`, it's `"1"` - a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out: [django - collecting data from a HTML <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786564/django-collecting-data-from-a-html-select).

Basically, you need a name on your select element in your HTML, and then you can access it with:

```
request.GET["nameOfYourAwesomeSelectList"]
```

Edit: Just noticed you're using the GET method. Is there a reason you're using GET to send the form data to the server?  Pure curiosity.

Edit 2:  For your error about form_to, notice you are only initializing it when the selected item is 1?  So when you select an item that isn't value 1, form_to is never initialized, and so when you create your RequestContext, it gets angry.  You'll want to either always initialize it, form_to, or change how you create your RequestContext when form_to is null.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a two-step process. In the first step, the user selects a "product type" from a drop down menu. In step 2, based on the earlier selection, I'll produce a form corresponding to the product type that the user chose. The way I'm currently implementing it is that each product type option in step 1 corresponds to a value (1, 2, 3...). I'm using the GET method to basically find that number, and based on that number, I want to produce a form corresponding to that product type. Do you think this could work?

Comment: Got it! The issue was that I was referencing "form_no == 1" as an integer whereas the data from GET was a string. Thanks for the help!