# How to collect data from select tags into Django views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I've seen a couple of documents on how to collect the data from a HTML select tag in Django but none of them resolved my problem. I have tried this Stackoverflow answer also [django - collecting data from a HTML <select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786564/django-collecting-data-from-a-html-select)

Here is my template code:

```
<form method = "post" action = "{% url 'index' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name = "drop1" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name = "drop2" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name = "drop3" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name = "drop4" >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<input  type = "submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my view:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == ["POST"]:
        a = request.POST['drop1']
        b = request.POST['drop2']
        c = request.POST['drop3']
        d = request.POST['drop4']
        # printing to check whether getting the selected values
        print a, b, c, d


    else:
        context_dict = {}
        return render(request, 'demo/dashboard.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.method` isn't an array so it never will equal one

`["POST"]` needs to be `"POST"`

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
```

That being said, *all* code paths in a view must return a response, so since its not clear what you want to do there, you can just remove the else statement and adjust the indentation of render to  return back to the same page after doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

```
context_dict = {}
return render(request, 'demo/dashboard.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you. Problem resolved. Was doing such a childish mistake :)